# GARCH model specification in R and Matlab

Tags: r, matlab, statistics, code-translation, economics

I want to do to GARCH modeling in R and for this I need do translate a Matlab code to R. I tried different packages, e.g. rugarch. However, I could not figure the right specification in R which is equivalent to the one in Matlab.

The Matlab code is as follows:

```
spec = garchset('C',0,'K',0.0001,'GARCH',0.9,'ARCH',0.05,'Display','off');
[Ca,Ea,LLa,A,Sa,Suma] = garchfit(spec,data);
```

Could somebody tell me how to put this in R?

Comment: just to be sure, you want to estimate a garch(1,1) model with fixed (all in this case) parameters? The `fGarch` package has quite the same syntax, but I don´t think you can fix parameter values like that.

Comment: Actually, I don't know what model is exactly estimated. I need to translate it to R but I am just not familiar with Matlab. So, I couldn't figure the order of the model so far.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The two lines of Matlab code stated in the question can be translated to R by using the *rugarch* package. At first, the mean model is set to have no AR and no MA part, so that it is simply a constant. Secondly, the variance model is *standard GARCH (sGARCH*) and has one GARCH and one ARCH component. Since in the provided Matlab code all parameters are fixed, one needs to include the `fixed.pars` command. Here, `mu`, `alpha1`, `beta1` and `omega` are the values of the unconditional mean, of the ARCH parameter, GARCH parameter and the intercept of the variance model, respectively.

```
install.packages("rugarch")
require(rugarch)
spec <- ugarchspec(mean.model=list(armaOrder=c(0,0)),
        variance.model=list(model = "sGARCH", garchOrder = c(1,1)), 
        fixed.pars=list(mu = 0, alpha1=0.05, beta1 = 0.9, omega = 0.0001))

garch_fit <- ugarchfilter(spec = spec, data = data)
```

The information contained in `[Ca,Ea,LLa,A,Sa,Suma]` can then be found by applying the following functions to `garch_fit`, e.g. `residuals(garch_fit, standardize = FALSE)` extracts the unstandardized residuals.

**coef**: Extracts the coefficients.
**fitted**: Extracts the filtered values.
**infocriteria**: Calculates and returns various information criteria.
**likelihood**: Extracts the likelihood.
**residuals**: Extracts the residuals. Optional logical argument standardize (default is FALSE) allows to extract the standardized residuals

More detailed information can be found in the [rugarch package manual guide.](https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/rugarch/rugarch.pdf)